# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent when using iTextsharp in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

In my mvc application I have used below code in actionFilter

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
        {
            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have used iTextsharp to generate pdf file, my code is as below

```
    public ActionResult GenerateSamplePDF()
    {
        //return null;

        try
        {
            Response.Clear();


            string pdfBody = string.Empty;
            pdfBody = "sample text for generating pdf";

            Document document = new Document();
            string fileName = "Sample.pdf";
            var fPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/BillGeneration/");
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fPath + fileName, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);

            hw.Parse(new StringReader(pdfBody));
            document.Close();


            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName + "");
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.WriteFile(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/BillGeneration/") + fileName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exxx = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(null);

    }
```

when executing I get exception "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent." how can I rewrite the code to remove this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.String,System.String%29) method?

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName + "");
return File(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/BillGeneration/") + fileName, "application/pdf");
```

[Response.Flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) sends output to client immediately, hence you cannot add headers afterwards.

Comment: I have used that to download to the server folder.